Extended Datatable - Custom picklist dropdown is being hidden
I'm working on a inline editable LWC Datatable where I have a multi-select picklist column (Followed https://techdicer.com/multiselect-picklist-in-lwc-datatable-inline-edit/) . The dropdown values are being hidden under parent component if there are very few records. Seeking Help.
Parent which hosts the Datatable:

This is Custom type Column :

CSS looks like this. .
slds-grid .slds-hyphenate {
    width: 100%
}

.slds-grid .slds-truncate {
    width: 100%
}

.picklist-section{
    margin-top: -1rem;
    margin-left: -0.5rem;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 10%;
}

.slds-listbox{
    z-index: 99999999999999999999999999!important;
}

the actual component that displays the dropdown is here:

CSS for the above:
.verticalAlign {
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 0px 5px !important;
        }
    
    .slds-dropdown {
        padding:0px !important;
        z-index: 999999999999999 !important;
    }
    
    .recordListBox {
        margin-top:0px !important;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    
    .slds-listbox li {
        padding: .45rem 0.7rem !important;
        display: flex;
    }
       
    .inputBox input {
        padding-left: 10px; 
    }
       
    .eachItem:hover {
        background-color: #F1F1F1;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    /* For Scrolling */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        display: none !important;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
         
    .slds-dropdown_fluid{
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

When one or 2 records are present table, It's impossible to see the dropdown. Please help me to make the list visible outside the component. Thanks in advance.
This is how it looks like.
For more records, it generally shows the list like this

Try adding this to your CSS: .THIS .slds-listbox{ overflow: initial; }

Thanks for the reply. Sadly it didn't work :(

Check out this solution here:
https://live.playg.app/play/dynamic-lightning-data-table
.You might try borrowing some of the CSS contained within the static resource on the components tab.
